# Plotting circles on two lines crosses

Tags: python, pine-script, indicator

So, I've been trying to modify some indicators to suit my trading strategy and I need to add a zero line to the SMI Ergodic Indicator (not oscillator) which I've done and also need circles to be plotted whenever the SMI line crosses the signal line but I don't have any idea on how to get through that. I want circles of a certain colour to be plotted whenever the two lines cross each other below the zero line and circles of another colour to be plotted whenever the two lines cross each other above the zero line. Anyone nice enough to help. Thanks y'all.

This is the code below. Everything was successful except that I don't know how to add what I said above.

```
//@version=4
study(title="SMI Ergodic Indicator", shorttitle="SMII", format=format.price, precision=4, resolution="")
longlen = input(20, minval=1, title="Long Period")
shortlen = input(5, minval=1, title="Short Period")
siglen = input(5, minval=1, title="Signal Line Period")
erg = tsi(close, shortlen, longlen)
sig = ema(erg, siglen)
plot(erg, color=#0094FF, title="SMI")
plot(sig, color=#FF6A00, title="Signal")
hline(0, title="Zero", color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_dashed, linewidth=1)
```

Comment: Please add your current code and output, showing what failed.

Comment: I've added it in the main post. Nothing failed actually just that I don't know how to add what I said above about plotting circles whenever the two lines cross.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (SMI Ergodic Indicator)", shorttitle="SMII", format=format.price, precision=4, resolution="")
longlen = input(20, minval=1, title="Long Period")
shortlen = input(5, minval=1, title="Short Period")
siglen = input(5, minval=1, title="Signal Line Period")
erg = tsi(close, shortlen, longlen)
sig = ema(erg, siglen)
plot(erg, color=#0094FF, title="SMI")
plot(sig, color=#FF6A00, title="Signal")
hline(0, title="Zero", color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dashed, linewidth=1)
plot(cross(sig, erg) and sig>0 ? sig : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
plot(cross(sig, erg) and sig<0 ? sig : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: I still have some problems with that, the green circles and red circles were all plotted on the zero line and not when the two lines crossed below or above the zero line.